# Propagate imports to other files

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, import

I created a `loader.js` file in which I imported all the dependencies into a `globalThis` object. Then I imported the `loader.js` module into the `index.js` file.
Everything works fine except IntelliSense in VSCode. This works, but only when the `loader.js` file is open in one of the editor tabs. When I close the `loader.js` file, the suggestions and types stop working in other files, where I use these imports.

How can I configure VSCode to see these imports when `loader.js` is closed?

Comment: our of curiosity, is the `typescript.tsserver.experimental.enableProjectDiagnostics` of any help?

Comment: @starball, nope, `typescript.tsserver.experimental.enableProjectDiagnostics` does not change this behavior.